# Access 2013, Extract number from field to use in search

Tags: ms-access

Have a sales proposal access database for work that has a field that you can put a earlier corresponding proposal number as a reference. If you click on a button under that field it will take you directly to that earlier record. There are times we have a prefix in front of the number A-12345, E-12345 or it might just be 12345.

I need to be able to grab just the number without the letter and - for the search to work correctly. Thanks

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUfwO.jpg) is the image of my screen

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table with columns Proposal and Reference and a single form with controls txtReference and txtProposal, put this code to the On_Click event of your form button (I'm using DAO):

```
Dim strProposal As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If Len(Nz(Me.txtReference, "")) < 1 Then
MsgBox "No reference number entered"
Else
For i = 1 To Len(Me.txtReference)
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Me.txtReference, i, 1)) Then
      strProposal = strProposal & Mid(Me.txtReference, i, 1)
      End If
Next
End If

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.MoveFirst
rs.FindFirst "Proposal = '" & StrProposal & "'"
If rs.NoMatch Then
MsgBox "Original proposal not found"
Else
Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
Me.txtProposal.SetFocus
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank You Rene, I will take a look at this and see how I can implement it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Make a typo in the code. The line rs.FindFirst "Proposal = '" & outstr & "'" should read rs.FindFirst "Proposal = '" & strProposal & "'", I've edited the code.